# Laravel eloquent query always returns all columns even when passing id

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have been racking my brain for a while now and I cannot come up with a reason why this is happening.

Basically, I have a table full of subscriber list names and I need to retrieve a single one for the details page of each. However, no matter how I try to retrieve the data it always returns every single row in the table. I have two relations on this model, as the subscriber lists have many users and, possibly, many organisations attached.

Here is the query I am currently using to attempt to retrieve the single record:

```php
$query = SubscriberList::with($loadRelations)->where('id', $subscriberListId)->firstOrFail();
```

This returns all rows.

I've also tried:

```php
$query = SubscriberList::with($loadRelations)->findOrFail($subscriberListId);
```

With the same results.

My relations are `users` and `organisations` respectively and are set up as follows in the SubscriberList model:

```php
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(User::class,SubscriberListsUsers::class,'user_id','id');
}

public function organisations()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Organisation::class, SubscriberListsOrganisations::class,'organisation_id','id');
}
```

Each one using a different pivot table to house the relations.

I am unsure why I'm getting the result I'm getting - can anyone shed any light on this? I haven't been using Eloquent for long so I may just have missed something obvious here.

EDIT:

The result of `dd($query)` :

```php
SubscriberList {#451
  #fillable: array:1 [
    0 => "name"
  ]
  #connection: "pgsql"
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:4 [
    "id" => 10
    "name" => "Michael"
    "created_at" => "2018-08-07 13:59:24"
    "updated_at" => "2018-08-07 13:59:24"
  ]
  #original: array:4 [
    "id" => 10
    "name" => "Michael"
    "created_at" => "2018-08-07 13:59:24"
    "updated_at" => "2018-08-07 13:59:24"
  ]
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #events: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:2 [
    "users" => Collection {#440
      #items: []
    }
    "organisations" => Collection {#454
      #items: []
    }
  ]
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

EDIT: Schemas for `users` and pivot table:

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('first_name');
    $table->string('last_name');
    $table->string('colour');
    $table->integer('organisation_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->string('requested_organisation')->nullable();
    $table->integer('sso_id')->nullable();
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('job_title')->nullable();
    $table->string('telephone')->nullable();
    $table->boolean('confirmed')->default(false);
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('organisation_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('organisations')
        ->onUpdate('cascade')
        ->onDelete('set null');
});

Schema::create('subscriber_lists_users', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('subscriber_list_id');
    $table->integer('user_id');

    $table->foreign('subscriber_list_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('subscriber_lists')
        ->onUpdate('cascade')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('users')
        ->onUpdate('cascade')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Comment: What's the result of `dd($query);`?

Comment: @Jonas  I have added it to the question

Comment: `dd($query)` did return a single row. `$query` is an instance `SubscriberList` meaning it corresponds to a single `SubscriberList` row.  Is the problem that you only want the identifier and not all columns?

Comment: @apokryfos Yes, I noticed that - but when I return the response back from the reducer it's always a list of all of the entries. Plus, there is a user in that subscriber list which doesn't show in the query result - it's just an empty array

Comment: @apokryfos When I return the results I use `$query->get()` - is this the problem?

Comment: `$query->get()` executes a new query, just return `$query`.

Comment: That returns a single result now - I just need to sort out the relationships I think now.

Comment: What do you mean by "sort out"? Remove from the result?

Comment: I need to figure out why the users attached to this list are not appearing in the array. There are definitely users attached to it in the pivot table but they are not showing so, basically, I need to fix it :)

Comment: Please post the migrations of `users` and `subscriber_lists_users`.

Comment: I have added them to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$query->get()` executes a new query, just return `$query`.

`users` uses the wrong relationship type:

```php
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'subscriber_lists_users');
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming then, based on this, that I do not need Models for the pivot tables?

Comment: No, only in special cases.